# Calculating $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (1,1)} \frac{x^2+y^2-2}{|x-1|+|y-1|}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

The function is not defined at $(1,1)$ and $0$ seems to be the limit, but I'm not sure how to prove this. How do I use $u=x-1$ and $v=y-1$ to find the limit?

Comment: Function is not _defined_ at $(1,1)$. There is a difference.

Comment: @Arthur noted, how can I use u=x-1 and v=y-1 to find the limit?